# Fourier Inversion and Convolution

Tags: analysis, harmonic-analysis

For $f, g$ in Schwartz function, I have
$\widehat{D^\alpha f}=|\xi|^\alpha{}\hat{f}(\xi).$

My question is that if

$$(|\xi|^\alpha\widehat{fg}(\xi))\check{}=(|\xi|^\alpha{})\check{}*(\widehat{fg}(\xi))\check{}$$

holds or not. Does it?

Comment: what ??? and the FT of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k}$ is $2 i \pi \xi_k \hat{f}(\xi)$

Comment: equivalently, it says that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k} = f \ast \frac{\partial \delta}{\partial x_k}$ where $\frac{\partial \delta}{\partial x_k}$ is the tempered distribution representing the $D^\alpha$ operator with $\alpha_k = 1, \alpha_m = 0$ if $m \ne k$, and in the world of FT of tempered distributions, $2 i \pi \xi_k $ is the FT of $\frac{\partial \delta}{\partial x_k} = D^\alpha \delta$